# How to get a software's hardware requirements when transplant from windows to Android?

Tags: android, opengl, opengl-es, hardware, requirements

I want to transplant a 3D program written in OpenGL on windows platform to Android, but I wonder if it can run smoothly on general Android platforms, so i want to estimate how much hardware resource is sufficient for it to run smoothly. It is some kind like the hardware requirements for a software or 3d game that a company will recommend the users. I don't know how can i get a hardware requirements of my program when transplant to Android.

i used gdebugger and it gave me some information but i don't think that is enough for me. Anyone here have some idea or solution? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If your program is simple enough, you could write up some estimates about texture fill rate, which is a pretty basic (and old) metric of rendering performance. Nearly every 3D chip comes with a theoretical fill rate, so you can get the theoretical numbers of both your desktop system and some Android phones.
The texture memory footprint is another thing that you can estimate, especially using gdebugger. Once again, these numbers are known for most chips.

This is a quick way to produce some numbers, obviously without any real life performance guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to test it on an actual device, and get an idea of what hardware works well. You could distribute a beta app and get some feedback too.

Comment: thx for your answer. That indeed would be the best way. But my boss want me to give him an evaluation report on the hardware requirements, so i have to do that before the transplanting job. Is there any acceptable alternative solution? i don't need it to be accurate. thx again:)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on feature set that you use. For example, if you use FBO, the device will have to support framebuffer extension. If you use MSAA, smooth line, the device will have support corresponding extensions. 
After listing down your requirements, you can use glGet to check for the device suppport
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml